# Limit Properties for Implicit Function

Tags: limits

Can we apply limits piecewise in, 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(g(x)) = \lim_{x \to 0} f\left(\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)\right)$$ in the case for 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \ln \left\vert(1+x)^{1/x}\right\vert  = \lim_{x \to 0} \left[\ln \left\vert \lim_{x \to 0}(1+x)^{1/x} \right\vert \right] = e.$$

Seen this operation while proving the first derivative of $e^x$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand why the first equation is problematic? (because the limit is over $n$ and the functions depends on $x$)

Comment: Thanks for the edits and correction, I'll try better to utilise MathJax @Yanko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many formulas by a comment: supposing that the $n$ is a typo and you are asking about if
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(g(x)) =
\lim_{x\to 0}f(\lim_{x\to 0}g(x))
$$
is true, consider: if the inner limit exists and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = a,$$
then:
$$f(\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)) = f(a),$$
and in the RHS you are asking by the limit of a *constant*:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}f(\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)) = 
\lim_{x\to 0}f(a) = f(a)
$$
...

Is true that if $f$ is continuous at $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}f(g(x)) =
f(\lim_{x\to 0}g(x))
$$
(or $x\to$ whatever)